# FEM - Linear grid covering a curved shape

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have a disk (or any other smooth curve) and wish to define a grid of squared cells everywhere, except for the boundary where they should be right triangles or pentagons with three right angles. In the following approach I get the disk shape but would like some advice to solve the boundary issue.

```
 << NDSolve`FEM`
 x0 = MeshRegion[ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/20^2]]["MakeLinear"]

   Module[{remove = Flatten[Position[Positive[Norm /@ MeshCoordinates[x0] - 1], True]]},MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[x0], Select[MeshCells[x0, 2] //. Thread[remove -> Nothing],Length @@ #1 == 4 & ]]]
```

(Here I only show a quarter)

[image]

Comment: Maybe using ToQuadMesh from the FEM add-ons is a viable way forward? Why do you need this specific type of a mesh?

Comment: @user21 Thank you. I need it for a problem in mechanics where the mesh lines represent stiff wires.

Comment: I think this is a non-trivial problem. One other thought (also far from trivial) is to make use of the DistMesh algorithm in the FEMAddOns and adjust that to generate quad elements in place of triangles.

Comment: @user21 Thank you. Any related examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not have an example for dist mesh ported to generate quad elements. Another option could be to use the [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package. That has a function called `DiskMesh` that generates a quad mesh from a disk, thought not in the way you have shown but perhaps it's still usable for your case. Have a look.

Comment: @user21 Thank you. That's useful.

Comment: One potential idea would be to calculate the intersections of a square grid with your line. Then if your line is parametrised you can sort the intersection points and create a discretised boundary. The next step would be to join this with the remaining points in the grid to create the mesh. One question, at the boundary you can also have quad elements with two right angles as well ?